# Firebase multilocation update timestamps

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm writing timestamps to multiple keys using a multi location update (https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-09-24-atomic-writes-and-more.html). Is there any guarantee of them being the same or in the same range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If multiple locations are set to `Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` in a single write, they will have the same value.

```
ref.update({
  'path/to/location1': Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
  'path/to/location2': Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
})
```

While you didn't ask: the value of `now` in the security rules will be the same too.